# ContentPresenter TextBlock.FontFamily binding not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, contentpresenter

I have a ContentPresenter and want to render each item with a different font by binding it to a FontFamily, but it's not working. The weird part is the binding works for a TextBlock but not for the ContentPresenter? Here's my xaml

```
<ContentPresenter 
    Width="100"
    Content="{Binding Name}"
    TextBlock.FontFamily="{Binding TextFont}"
    TextBlock.Foreground="{Binding BindedTextColor}"/>
<TextBlock
    Text="{Binding FontName}"
    FontFamily="{Binding TextFont}"
    Foreground="{Binding BindedTextColor}"/>
```

Which renders this:

[image]

Both the TextBlock and ContentPresent bind their FontFamily to TextFont. Why isn't the word "residential" also rendered with the Algerian font family?

If I change `TextBlock.FontFamily="{Binding TextFont}"` to a hardwire like this `TextBlock.FontFamily="Algerian"`I get this

[image]

How do I get it working with a binding?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Output pane in VS at runtime, you'll find that the bindings on the ContentPresenter are looking at the ContentPresenter's `DataContext` for the properties `TextFont` and `BindedTextColor`, as expected -- but the `DataContext` is not what you expect. It's the `ContentPresenter`'s `Content` property.

[`ContentPresenter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter?view=netframework-4.8) is a very specialized control. You don't want one here. Use it only as directed, in a `ControlTemplate`. For this application, use a `ContentControl` or a `Label`.

If you set those properties without a binding, the DataContext isn't an issue and you get what you expect.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'TextFont' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=966822854)'. BindingExpression:Path=TextFont; DataItem='String' (HashCode=966822854); target element is 'ContentPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'FontFamily' (type 'FontFamily')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'BindedTextColor' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=966822854)'. BindingExpression:Path=BindedTextColor; DataItem='String' (HashCode=966822854); target element is 'ContentPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'Foreground' (type 'Brush')

Whenever a binding does something obviously wrong, look in the output pane for errors. If you don't solve the problem right there, add a trace and you'll get piles of debugging information in the output pane:

```
<ContentPresenter 
    Width="100"
    Content="{Binding ID}"
    TextBlock.FontFamily="{Binding TextFont, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"
    TextBlock.Foreground="{Binding BindedTextColor}"
    />
```